# ssh known_hosts entry from hostname and host key

Tags: ssh

How can I create an entry in a ssh known_hosts file from hostname and host key?

I want to do it without trying to connect to the remote system, automaticaly loading the key over untrusted network and adding it to ~/.ssh/known_hosts by answering "yes" and hoping that there is currently no man in the middle attac.
Instead I want to go to the remote system copy some files from /etc/ssh to an USB storage pen, or floppy disk, carry that media to the other system and create the known_hosts entry from the content of that media.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hostname,ip ssh-rsa keycontentshere

ssh-rsa might be different if the key is generated using AES or another method.  Of course, making a connection to the machine in question should automatically create the host key.

Comment: echo gvcentostest $(cat gvcentostest/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub)>>All/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts did it. My question was caused by my frustration about the content of /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key.pub which doesn't fit to the known_hosts files. Thank you for the answer. It made me have a closer look into /etc/ssh . I do apologize.